# Jetson.GPIO is installed but cannot be imported?

Tags: python-3.x, gpio, servo, nvidia-jetson-nano, adafruit-circuitpython

i’m working in a virtual environment with all my packages (blinka, servokit, Jetson.GPIO) have been installed successfully, but when i try to import Jetson.GPIO, it keep telling me that i have not installed the library. Please help me with this error. Thank you.
This is the terminal output:

```bash
(tomatovenv) hietrn@Hien:~/tomato3$ python3.6 -m pip install Jetson.GPIO
Looking in indexes: Simple index, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Requirement already satisfied: Jetson.GPIO in ./tomatovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.1.3)

(tomatovenv) hietrn@Hien:~/tomato3$ python3.6 simpleservo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “simpleservo.py”, line 1, in
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
File “/home/hietrn/tomato3/tomatovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_servokit.py”, line 35, in
import board
File “/home/hietrn/tomato3/tomatovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/board.py”, line 148, in
from adafruit_blinka.board.nvidia.jetson_nano import *
File “/home/hietrn/tomato3/tomatovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/board/nvidia/jetson_nano.py”, line 3, in
from adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.tegra.t210 import pin
File “/home/hietrn/tomato3/tomatovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/tegra/t210/pin.py”, line 4, in
import Jetson.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘Jetson.GPIO’
```

I'm trying to control a servo with the GPIO and adafruit servokit library